# What plugins are there for editing ASCII charts in Vim or Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, vim, plugins, charts

I remember seeing a plugin in some editor (I think, it was Vim or Eclipse) for editing text-based ASCII charts that look like so:

```
+-----------+               +-----------+
|  Class A  | ------------> |  Class B  |
+-----------+               +-----------+
```

Is anyone aware of such a plugin? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Probably the most functional plugin for simple ASCII drawing (straight
lines, arrows, ellipses, rectangles, etc.) in Vim is [DrawIt!](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=40).
Another option (which may be outdated) could be [sketch.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=705). Both
of them provide shortcuts for drawing at least arrows and boxes.

Answer (score 3):

You can search it on vim.org:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=ascii&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search

Most popular results:

- [DrawIt!](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=40)
- [CharTab](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=898)
- [boxdraw](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=173)

Comment: It's impossible to create diagrams using `CharTab` plugin, which, in fact, provides ASCII character table viewer.

Comment: And `boxdraw` does not suit well for diagram drawing automation.  For example, it has no simple way to draw arrows in it.

Answer (score 1):

You may have been thinking of [asciio](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-Asciio/lib/App/Asciio.pm#NAME), which isn't part of any editor -- it's an editor on its own that lets you create ASCII diagrams from within a nice little GUI. Here are some videos of it in use: [one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiOHYNHo_Nw), [two](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vpth3yTT4Rs), [three](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OQfLgaC3eE).

On the other side of the problem, you might be interested in [ditaa](http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/), which takes ASCII diagrams (including some of the very same things that asciio produces) and turns them into nice graphical diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're referring to Artist Mode in emacs:  http://www.cinsk.org/emacs/emacs-artist.html